# Running a bash function

Tags: bash, slurm

In order to easily change the version of a package I'm using in my software, I generated a `bash` interface with functions that calls the underlying software. In that way, my main script can keep the same interface and I only need to change/add a helper script per version to be used:

helper_v1.sh:

```
method1() {
    cmd1 params
}

method2() {
    cmd1 other_params
}
```

helper_v2.sh:

```
method1() {
    cmd2 params
}

method2() {
    cmd2 other_params
}
```

Now I need to start those commands via `srun` to distribute the work across different nodes. So I'm trying (inside a script launched with `sbatch`):

```
source helper_v2.sh
srun method1 params
```

But it fails with the error:

```
slurmstepd: error: execve(): method1: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to use those `bash` functions with `srun`? It will be a pity to have to reimplement all of them as individual scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`source` only works if you're inside a single bash process. Functions don't really work well across commands. You could perhaps get it to work by exporting your functions with `export -f method1 method2`, but I don't recommend going down that road.

Some encapsulation would be better. What you can do is let the helper scripts be called like real programs by having them take the function to be called as an argument. It could be as simple as adding a `case` statement:

```
method1() {
    cmd2 params
}

method2() {
    cmd2 other_params
}

case "$1" in
    method1) method1;;
    method2) method2;;
    *) echo "$1: no such function" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```

Or you could go even more bare bones and write `"$@"` to simply call whatever the caller passes on the command-line without checking what it is.

```
method1() {
    cmd2 params
}

method2() {
    cmd2 other_params
}

"$@"
```

Usage in either case would be:

```
helper_v2.sh method2
```

Comment: So clever! I was already exporting my functions, but `srun` expects a binary anyways.  One workaround would be to run `bash -c "whatever"`, but it comes with its own set of issues regarding quoting. But your idea is really simple to implement and solves the issue so... thanks a lot!