# Parallel function call in slurm sbatch script

Tags: bash, function, parallel-processing, slurm

I want to unzip big files, so I made a sbatch script.

My script defines and uses a function for unzipping a file, and I want the job to make multiple call of this function in parallel.

This is my script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=gunzip_hs2
#SBATCH --output %x-%j.out
#SBATCH --partition=lirmm
#SBATCH --account=atgc
#SBATCH --time=23:59:00
#SBATCH -n 4

gzipkeep() {
    filename=$(basename $1)
    gunzip -c -- "$1" > "uncompressed_fastq_files_H_Sapiens2/${filename::-3}"
}

export -f gzipkeep

mkdir -p "uncompressed_fastq_files_H_Sapiens2"

for file in /home/bunelp/scratch/jobs/fastq_files_H_Sapiens2/*.gz
do
    srun -n1 --exclusive gzipkeep $file &
done

wait
```

The problem is that `srun` doesn't know the function  `gzipkeep` defined above, and I get the following error:

```bash
slurmstepd: error: execve(): gzipkeep: No such file or directory
```

I guess I'm missing something because I didn't find anyone with my problem, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. My function is very simple so I could find a workaround without using it, but I want to understand how I could do if I had a much more complex function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184031/running-a-bash-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184031/running-a-bash-function) provided in the comment by ***@Niloct***, will give you the workaround to utilise the function in your srun script. Nevertheless, why the function (as argument in `srun fn_name`) is not working as straightforward as a command (for eg: `srun hostname`) can be explained as follows.

consider the following call:

```
srun -n N executable args
```

`srun` uses the [path resolution](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) to locate the `executable` provided in the command. The executable is resolved as follows ([See this link](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html#SECTION_EXECUTABLE-PATH-RESOLUTION)):

1. If executable starts with ".", then path is constructed as: current working directory / executable
2. If executable starts with a "/", then path is considered absolute.
3. If executable can be resolved through PATH. See path_resolution(7).
4. If executable is in current working directory.

A corresponding file name matching the provided function name is not found using path resolution by `srun` and hence results in the error `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I understand well, there is no way to call a function with srun like I did? I have to call a script?

Comment: Yes, it is my understanding. Under the hood, all launchers uses exec family of functions and as an argument for exec, a file (path to a file) is required.